# Why appended input field submit not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

When user enter the `key press` I used Jquery to submit `form` and after I append another `<input>` field for another input. But the problem is appended input field submit not working... Instead it expecting the old one.

**Code**

// html

```
<div class="ten columns">
  <input id="txt_name" class="u-full-width" name="a" type="text" autofocus>
</div>
```

// javascript

```
$('#txt_name').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $.getJSON('/_main_submit', {
        a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
    },  function(data){
        $('.after_sub').append(
              '<div class="ten columns">'+
                '<input id="txt_name" class="u-full-width" name="a" type="text" autofocus>'+
              '</div>'
          )
        $('div input').focus();

    })
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one element with a certain id in the DOM. Use classes instead of id's for your input fields. Your new input also has the same name, that should be changed, too, if you expect the form to have more than one input field.

Comment: ah.. okay.. but I confused whether go with multiple or single.